# How to ensure that methods called from same thread use the same DB session

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

In our system we have multi-threaded processing engine. During processing each thread  calls methods to retrieve data from the database. We determined that performance is greatly improved if methods called from the same thread use the same DB session (sessions are coming from the pool of course).

Is there any standard way in Spring to ensure such thing or we have to come up with our own custom solution?

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that same methods can be called in different context where they should use a standard way of getting the session from the pool

Comment: are you refering to hibernate sessions? If so you can use the current-session concept in hibernate to maintain one session per thread.

Comment: @Yoni See my question update. How would it work then?

Comment: I'm surprised that performance is any better.  I assume the patter for each method is something like:

get db from pool, 
, do db work
, commit/rollback
, return to pool.

Is that the case?

Comment: @Dave Actually we only have reads in this case, but we suspect that hibernate caching has lot to do with it. But it is the case that each method is getting session from the pool using hibernate template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not see Spring anywhere in your question. So I assume you want a simple utility to do this.

```
class SessionUtil {
    private ThreadLocal currentSession;

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        if(currentSession.get() == null) {
             Session s = //create new session
             currentSession.set(s);
        }
        return (Session)currentSession.get();
    }
}
```

The Thread local will ensure that within the same thread it is always the same session. If you are using Spring then the classes/utilities mentioned above (in other responses) should be perfect.

Comment: His question is **tagged** with spring.

Comment: This is one of the solutions we discussed, but i was hoping to find something in Spring to make it transparent

Answer (score 2):

Spring has a class called `TransactionSynchronizationManager`. It stores the current `Session` in a `ThreadLocal`. The `TransactionSynchronizationManager` is not recommended for use by the developer, but you can try using it.

```
Session session = ((SessionHolder) 
   TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(sessionFactory)).getSession();
```

(if you are using `EntityManager`, simply replace "Session" with "EntityManager").

You can have the `sessionFactory` injected in your bean - it is per-application.

Take a look at [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=26171) discussion.

Other options, which I think are preferable to manual thread-handling are:

- [Thread pooling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html)
- [Spring batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/cases/async.html)
- [Spring-JMS integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3.0 has a concept of thread-scoped beans (hovewer, this scope is not registered by default, see docs): [3.5 Bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes), [3.5.5.2 Using a custom scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom-using)

**EDIT**:
I say about this:

> **Thread-scoped beans**  As of Spring 3.0,
>   a thread scope is available, but is
>   not registered by default. For more
>   information, see the documentation for
>   [SimpleThreadScope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html). For
>   instructions on how to register this
>   or any other custom scope, see
>   [Section 3.5.5.2, “Using a custom
>   scope”](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom-using).

Answer (score 0):

Spring coordinates database sessions, connections and threads through it's [Transaction Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#transaction) (actually, using its `TransactionSynchronizationManager` - see description [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#tx-resource-synchronization) - but you *really* don't want to mess with that directly, it's fearsome). If you need to coordinate your threads, then this is by far the simplest way of doing it.

How you choose to use the framework, however, is up top you.